# How to call a function according to the value entered?

Tags: python, function

I built functions that search for the words by direction, right left, up,  down , and diagonally.
Each such function returns the word if it appears and the number of times it appears.
I actually built a separate function for each direction so that there could be a word that is in the search up and not in the search down.
I now want to build a function that accepts the word list ,and the matrix structure as a list of lists.
In addition it gets the direction in which it should look up the list of words, can be two directions and more.
I want to summon any function I have already written according to the desired direction but I have two problems: 1. I do not want to use `if 'u' in directions return upper (words, pattern (matrix))` for every direction because it is too long.
2.If i want a word to appear in two directions for example - both in the search above('u') and in the search below('d') I want to make a union so that instead of a word appearing to me in two different tupels -
(word, 1),(word, 1) but I will get one tuple
(word,2)   the total appearance number.

```
def fins_words(word,pattern,direction_letters):
    letters_lst=['u','d','r','l','w','x','y','z']
    functions_lst=[upper(word, pattern),down(word, pattern),right(word, pattern),
                   left(word, pattern),up_right_diagonals(word, pattern),
                   up_left_diagonals(word, pattern),
                   down_right_diagonals(word, pattern),down_left_diagonals(word, pattern)]
    for i in range(8):
        if letter_lst[i] in direction_letters:
            return letter_lst[i]
```

```
def right(word_list, pattern):
    word_occur = dict()
    one_word = [''.join(row) for row in pattern]
    for word in word_list:
        for string in one_word:
            count = string.count(word)
            if count > 0:
                if word in word_occur:
                    word_occur[word] += 1
                else:
                    word_occur[word] = 1

    return [item for item in word_occur.items()]
```

pattern- matrix (list of lists of letters-[['a','b'],['d','e']])
word-words list for search in the matrix.
letter - the direction of sercg 'u' for up
'd' for down .....
for example-

```
print(right(['apple','app','lg'],[['a','p','p','l','e'],['a','p','p','d','n']])
```

will return ('apple',1), (app,2)
(wont return 'lg' beacuse it is nor appear)

Comment: You need to provide more of a [mre] — something that includes a call the function and the values of the arguments being passed to to it. Don't forget to define everything being reference by the code. like `letter_lst`.

Comment: It would be *extremely* useful to see the implementation of even just one of these helpers as an example (`upper`, etc).  It's not clear whether they return a tuple or a bool or what.

Comment: put it in the question please, code formatting doesn't work in comments

Comment: now I almost have the whole picture but you deleted the part that explains what `word` and `pattern` and `letter` are... your helper takes a `word_list`, so now I'm confused about whether your original function also takes a list or if it's actually a single word and you have to pack it into a list (and then unpack the result) when you call the helpers.  And you already fooled me once with a parameter called `letter` that was actually a list of letters.  :P

Comment: yes I am sorry about that, because I tried so many times I got into a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your two lists with a dict that maps each letter to its corresponding function:

```
direction_funcs = {
    'u': upper,
    'd': down,
    'r': right,
    'l': left,
    'w': up_right_diagonals,
    'x': up_left_diagonals,
    'y': down_right_diagonals,
    'z': down_left_diagonals,
}
```

and then you can do something like this to aggregate the results of calling all the helpers according to `direction_letters` (I'm going to rename your word list parameter from `word` to `words` so the code is legible):

```
results = {word: 0 for word in words}
for c in direction_letters:
    for word, count in direction_funcs[c](words, pattern):
        results[word] += count
return list(results.items())
```

Comment: It is not working. error-"unhashable type: 'list'"                                                the input is -letter= list of letters, word- list of strings(words), pattern- list of list of letters(e.g [['i','j'],['h','i']])

Comment: Yes, because you created a dictionary whose key should be `hashable`. List is not hashable. If you have a list of letters to process, you will have to do the dictionary look ups one by one

Comment: I don’t understand ,what do i need to do?

Comment: You need to provide more code for anyone to be able to tell you that.  I took my best guess in this answer, but you didn't give an example of what `letter` contains or what result you want to get for that example.  Note that I edited my answer to account for `letter` actually being a list, but I'm still just guessing at what you might be trying to do.

Comment: thank you for you comment, I tried to explain my self better.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me, maybe because I don't know what `upper()` etc return or how that relates to counting the word in the matrix.  (What does "up search" mean???)  And you didn't actually give the desired result of your sample input so I'm not even sure I understand what you mean by "counting".  Maybe you want the `sum` of the thing I put in my answer?

Comment: Okay, the missing piece was that the helpers return **lists of `(word, count)` tuples** -- it's impossible to solve it without knowing that!

Comment: yes, i wrote this in my question. I guess i wasent clear ,sorry.

Comment: thank you for your help, the code you sent is amazing but i have 2 problems:1. the fubction returns me (word,0) if the word not appears insted of not returning the word at all( only word that appears should return)      2. the direction letters are string and not list.

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you to solve -- it's easy to filter out the zero results (e.g. in a list comprehension) and convert the direction letters according to whatever format they're actually in.  The lack of an MRE makes it hard for me to debug in a way where I can give you code you can run as-is, but hopefully I've given you enough to point you in the right direction!